# Polynomial Evaluation using python

Tags: python, polynomials

Evaluate a polynomial given a value for **x**. The input is a list of coefficients and value for **x** . The output is the polynomial sum
evaluated at **x**.

Comment: It occurs to me that you use recursion. You think in a base case!

Comment: What about `x**2` in your example? Coefficient is `0` or do I misunderstand?

Comment: The coefficient for the 2nd root is zero

Comment: They probably ask for [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Answer (score 1):

This is an option that does not use any exponentiation operator:

```
def pol_eval(a, x):
    result = 0
    # for every n in 0..len(a)-1
    for n, a_n in enumerate(a):
        # compute x^n
        x_power_n = 1
        for i in range(n):
            x_power_n *= x
        # add a_n * x^n to the final result
        result += a_n * x_power_n
    return result
```

Example:

```
a = [1,2,0,3] # coefficients
x = 1.5
print(pol_eval(a, x)) # 14.125
```

Comment: I started with this:
"p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
x = int(input())
n = len(poly)"

Comment: @M_C Are you sure you want to do this `x = int(input())`? This is converting your text into an integer, so for example you can't input a value like 1.5 for x. You should do `x=float(input())`, and then call my function `pol_eval(p, x)`. Same thing for the coefficients: use `float`, not `int`!

Comment: I did, but it's not printing the answer

Comment: @M_C If you don't provide me more details I can't help you. Update your question please.

Comment: This is what I did**
p = [float(x) for x in input().split()]
x = float(input())
n = len(poly)
def pol_eval(p, x):
    result = 0
    for n, p_n in enumerate(p):
        x_power_n = 1
        for i in range(n):
            x_power_n *= x
        result += p_n * x_power_n
    return result    
print (pol_eval(p, x))

Comment: When I run it, after inputting the coefficients in p and the value of x, it just disappeared, not showing the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion, think about how you can write out a polynomial.
You can reference Horner's method on wikipedia.

```
def evaluate_poly(x, coefficients):
    if len(coefficients) == 1:
        return coefficients[0]
    return coefficients[0] + evaluate_poly(x, coefficients[1:])*x

a = [1, 2, 0, 3]
x = 1.5
print(evaluate_poly(x, a)) # 14.125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop where you accumulate the products of coefficients with a progressively increasing power of x obtained by multiplying by x on each iteration:

```
a      = [1,2,0,3]
x      = 1.5

result = 0
xPower = 1
for coeff in a:
    result += coeff * xPower
    xPower *= x

print(result) # 14.125 = 1 + 2x + 0x^2 + 3x^3 = 1 + 3 + 0 + 10.125
```

Note that this can be further simplified by going backwards in the coefficients list and mutiplying the previous result by x before adding the coefficient:

```
result = 0
for coeff in reversed(a):
    result = coeff + result * x
```